# How to handle loading redux state of single items to show a loading indicator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

how do you handle async state like loading in redux store for partial loaded data?

Imagine you have a redux store with a user reducer which holds every loaded user and you have initially 10 users fully loaded (their ids, names etc) + next 10 user ids which are not fully loaded and need to be fetch in a later step.

Then with an action you can load the 11th user by fetching by id and need to show loading for that request.

Would you store all 20 users as 1 javascript object/user in an array where each entry has an isLoading variable and read/modify from that by id? Or are there any other approaches for this use case?

Best and thank you

Comment: You can make one Http-interceptor which will call every time when your Http request is called and once it's called you need to invoke the loader and once you receive the response you need to stop it so this way you don't need to handle manually for each and every request

Comment: The default approach is to let the list component fetch a list of basic user data including an id and let the detail component fetch additional information by id. You can either let the detail component fetch it every time it mounts or you can check if the additional information is already available first (either by using a flag like you suggested or just by checking a certain field being there if it is a required field). The loading state can be kept local to the detail component depending on if it actually fetches data while mounting.

Comment: @DhavalPatel nice idea but there are also a lot of ongoing requests in the background and I dont want to confuse the user by showing loading indicators for those

Comment: @trixn thanks, just for clarification, would you make the request in the react component? I would like not to do that but rather in the action creator because I may use this in another component as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set `isPatching` state per record. In this case an `.isPatching` boolean is added to each record in the store, set to true at start, false at end. Per record status.

Answer (score 0):

### react-redux example:

- if we loading data from the database then over loader going to be true and when we get our data in componentWillReceiveProps then our loader going to false.

```js
   /**
    * home_container : component for home 
    * it is conected with redux store
    * 
    */
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { getBooks ,clearBook } from '../actions';
    import BookItem from '../widgetsUI/book_item';


    class HomeContainer extends Component {
        //loader
        state = {
            loading : true
        }
        //getBooks from database
        componentWillMount(){
            this.props.dispatch(getBooks(5,0,'desc'))
        }

   //if we receiving new props
    componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
       // console.log(nextProps)
        this.setState({
            loading : false
        })
    } 
        //rendering bookItems
        renderItems = (books) => (
            books.list ? 
            books.list.map(item => (
                <BookItem {...item} key = { item._id } />
            ))
            : null
        )
        //loadmore button
        loadmore = () => {
            this.setState({
                loading : true
            })
            const count = this.props.books.list.length;
            this.props.dispatch(getBooks(5,count,'desc',this.props.books.list))
        }
        
        render() {

            if(this.state.loading){
                return <div className="loader"> Loading... </div>
            }
            return(
                <div>
                {this.renderItems(this.props.books)}
                <div className='loadmore'
                    onClick={this.loadmore}
                >Load More</div>
            </div>
            )
        }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state){
        //console.log(state)
        return {
            books : state.books
        }

    }

    export default   connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeContainer);
```

### I hope this will help you

Comment: thanks but iam familiar with using a flag to show the loading state, my question was more about best practices for loading indicator of single items in the reducer like users object in an array where I can show the loading indicator of each single user entry

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload try this you can build your custom placeholder and handle loading. Demo https://twobin.github.io/react-lazyload/examples/#/placeholder?_k=r6i3da

Comment: sorry but i dont think you got my point, i try to further describe: iam not concerned how to display the loading but about the architectural choice how to structure the loading flags in my redux store in the "best" way possible